# Unexpected Error with FilteredElementCollector in pyrevit

Tags: python, revit-api, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

Beginner in python, pyRevit, and Revit API so my apologies if I'm phrasing my question poorly.  Today I used pyRevit to develop a simple pushbutton tool that worked, and then after a few minutes stopped working without anything being changed (that I'm aware of)

My tool adds all groups with excluded elements to the selection.  It worked perfectly for a time, then started throwing this error, which I can't make heads or tails of:

Exception: The input argument "document" of function `anonymous-namespace'::FilteredElementCollector_constructor or one item in the collection is null at line 326 of file d:\ship\2018_px64\source\revit\revitdbapi\APIFilteredElementCollectorProxy.cpp. Parameter name: document

The path in the error message isn't one I recognize on my computer.  Here's the relevant code (the traceback goes to line 24, which is "groups = FilteredElementCollector...":

```
from pyrevit import script
from pyrevit.framework import List
from pyrevit.framework import clr
from pyrevit import revit, DB

clr.AddReference("RevitServices")
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument

clr.AddReference("RevitNodes")
import Revit
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.Elements)
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.GeometryConversion)

clr.AddReference("RevitAPI")
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *


groups = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_IOSModelGroups).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements()

selection = revit.get_selection()

SelectionIds = []

for group in groups:
    name = group.Name
    if "(members excluded)" in name:
        SelectionIds.append(group.Id)

selection.set_to(SelectionIds)
```

Thanks a lot for any solutions, or even help deciphering the error message.

Comment: does this happen with all your revit models or only on a specific file?

Comment: pyRevit uses cached engines in Rocket mode to run the scripts faster. This means that the modules will stay in memory between executions. So any change in loaded documents state will render `doc` as none. Always refer to document using `revit.doc` or grab it from the application object. Read here: https://eirannejad.github.io/pyRevit/pyrevit/update/2017/11/08/45beta.html. Also importing * is a bad idea `from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *`. You have already imported the DB so always refer to the types using the DB namespace e.g `DB.Element`

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I've found what to import and when to be the most difficult part of learning Python/pyrevit.

I understand revit.doc, would you mind clarifying what you mean by "grab it from the application document"?

Also, are there any good resources for what exactly is in these various imports (revit, DB, clr etc.)?